# Passing reference to Dom element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
          <div class="row">
            <div class="text" #radioButtonWrapper id="radioButtonWrapper" style="display:inline-block;">Płeć</div>
            <div class="data">
              <div id="genderSection" style="display:inline-block;">
                <radiobutton [(model)]="gender" name="plec" value="Female" (modelChange)="reciveRadioButtonVal($event, radioButtonWrapper)" required>Kobieta</radiobutton>
                <radiobutton [(model)]="gender" name="plec" value="Male" (modelChange)="reciveRadioButtonVal($event, radioButtonWrapper)" required>Mężczyzna</radiobutton>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

 reciveRadioButtonVal($event, radiobutton) {
    console.log(radiobutton);
    console.log(radiobutton.nativeElement);
}
```

first console.log() display

```
<div _ngcontent-c3="" class="text" id="radioButtonWrapper" style="display:inline-block;">Płeć</div>
```

second console.log() display undefinded

My question is How to get id for this element

Comment: Try console.log(radiobutton.id)

Comment: @DaniëlCamps thanks it's works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the properties you see in red almost like they're javascript object properties, so in this case
`console.log(radiobutton.id)` should do the trick